# Error when returning clob data in LinkedHashmap

Tags: mybatis, micronaut

I am using mybatis in micronaut.. and I have a dynamic sql that returns `LinkedHashMap` ,I don;t know what columns or their datatype in a table.. when the datatype for a column is a `CLOB` then the micronaut cannot serialize the hashmap. Here is my xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper  PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/ibatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="xxx.datasource.VocabMapper">
    <select id="getProjectVocab" parameterType="map" resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap">
        SELECT * FROM ${tableName}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Following is how I setup the factory

```java
@Factory
public class TCPRFactory {
    @Inject
    @Named("default")
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public TCPRFactory(@Named("default") DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Named("tcprDBFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() {
        TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();

        Environment environment = new Environment("prod", transactionFactory, dataSource);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
        configuration.addMappers("xxx.datasource");

        return new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
    }
}
```

When the clob data column exists.. I get this error

```
{REVIEW=abc, RANKING=12, DESCRIPTION=xczczcz, TEMP_COL=oracle.sql.CLOB@141f56f9}]] to JSON: No serializer found for class oracle.jdbc.internal.Monitor$CloseableLock and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["TEMP_COL"]->oracle.sql.CLOB["physicalConnection"]->oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection["monitorLock"])"
```

what might be my options to get around this issue ? I cannot do a `resultMap` as I don;t know what my columns will be.. and not sure how to setup global typehandler for CLOB in micronaut.

Any suggestions will be super helpful

Comment: It depends on what you want to receive. If, for example, you want to receive the CLOB data as `String`, you can tell MyBatis to use the built-in `ClobTypeHandler` i.e. `configuration.getTypeHandlerRegistry().register(Object.class, JdbcType.CLOB, ClobTypeHandler.class)`. Note that the 'universal query' _usually_ is not a good idea.